# Force on charge carriers in a simple circuit

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electronics

Is it true that in a simple circuit where a simple conducting wire is connected to a battery, the force on each charge carrier is same in magnitude ? If yes, then can you explain how? I know that if there is a single charge, the force acting upon that charge will be same irrespective of its position in the wire, but in a conductor there are other charges too, one after another and this will result in each charges having a different force acting upon it due to **repulsion** from other charges present in the conductor.

Comment: Who claimed that all charges see the same force? Can you quote their exact wording?

Comment: @ThePhoton It is saying steady current, which means each charge carries must have same force acting on it. Otherwise how is it a steady state?

Comment: Who is saying it? What exact words did they use to say it? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @ThePhoton In this video at 2:04 He is saying the forces are same everywhere in the circuit. it isn't from a book https://youtu.be/roIbMxiVH7U?feature=shared

Comment: He says the forces are "pretty much the same", not "the same". That's an important detail you left out of your question post. Please update your question post to clarify your question.

Comment: At 2:04 he's also **not** talking about steady state conditions, he's talking about the transient in the first picoseconds after the battery is connected to the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it true that in a simple circuit where a simple conducting wire is connected to a battery, the force on each charge carrier is same in magnitude ?

No, it is not.

First, in a microscopic view, charge carriers frequently interact with the material lattice (with the nuclear charges or with the phonon field, depending on how deep a model you want to use) so that their velocities are randomized and their temperature is kept in equilibrium with the lattice. Each of these interactions applies an impulsive force on an individual carrier, making it experience a force that is, in that moment, not the same as the force on the other carriers.

But what is it your source likely meant by their claim?

> in a conductor there are other charges too, one after another and this will result in each charges having a different force acting upon it due to repulsion from other charges present in the conductor.

Macroscopically, the charge is distributed randomly but (when averaged over a reasonable amount of time and volume) uniformly through the conductor, so all the free charges see essentially the same force *due to the applied potential from the battery and from the other surrounding charges*.

This may break down at the surface of the conductor where the other charges are all distributed to one side of a given position. And in real conductors we do see charge (either positive or negative) build up on the conductor surface, an effect that we model with *parasitic capacitance* between the wire and other objects.

In comments you added

> It is saying steady current, which means each charge carries must have same force acting on it.

*Steady state* current does not mean that each charge carrier must have the same force acting on it. It only means that the conditions remain constant over time, and that a non-changing behavior can be achieved in the given system (for example, it does not oscillate).

The concept of a steady state current is a simplifying approximation used to make circuit analysis easier, while still giving results that are "close enough" to reality. All of circuit theory is based on simplifying assumptions: That charge is infinitely divisible rather than quantized, that magnetic fields don't affect the wiring between elements in the circuit, that charge doesn't build up in the wiring between the elements, that the circuit isn't big enough to generate radio waves, etc. These approximations give quite accurate results when analyzing many every-day circuits. But they aren't meant to give you the ability to analyze the behavior of individual charge carriers in the wires, or the light-speed delay between a potential being applied at one end of the wire and a response being seen at the other end, etc.

If you look more closely (considering very short time intervals, very small currents, or very narrow wires), you find that the current through the wire can not be truly uniform over time, because of the quantization of charge. When this becomes important in a circuit, we have to give up the steady state approximation and characterize this behavior as "shot noise".

Comment: I understand now!